# Modify the "Edit Account Information" page in Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I'm trying to overwrite two templates in my layout file, I want to overwrite customer/form/register.phtml and customer/form/edit files.

Here's my layout.xml file :

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
<customer_account_create>
    <reference name="customer_form_register">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>myModule/customer/form/register.phtml</template></action>
        <block type="persistent/form_remember" name="persistent.remember.me" template="persistent/remember_me.phtml" />
        <block type="core/template" name="persistent.remember.me.tooltip" template="persistent/remember_me_tooltip.phtml" />
    </reference>
    <reference name="customer_form_edit">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>myModule/customer/form/edit.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
</customer_account_create>
```

It works for the register.phtml file but not for the other one :/

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're in the wrong layout handle to overwrite the `customer/form/edit.phtml` template. Use `<customer_account_edit>` and `<reference name="customer_edit">`

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

I tried :

`<customer_account_edit>
        <reference name="customer_edit">
                <action method="setTemplate">   <template>myModule/customer/form/edit.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
  </customer_account_edit>`

but this didn't work either :/